# How can I start kube-controller-manager with config file?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-controller-manager

I'm using `hyperkube` to start `kube-controller-manager` docker container. In order to rotate the kubernetes CA I followed [this doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/manual-rotation-of-ca-certificates/). I have to point the KCM `client-ca` and `cluster-signing-cert` to different certs. Automating this is difficult because KCM process uses command line arguments.

I don't see any option [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-controller-manager/). Does anyone know a way of migrating command line arguments to a `config.yaml` file for `kube-controller-manager`?

NOTE: My question is about starting the KCM process with config file just like how we have one for kubelets [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/#start-a-kubelet-process-configured-via-the-config-file).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubernetes kube-controller-manager. How can I apply a flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60767427/kubernetes-kube-controller-manager-how-can-i-apply-a-flag)

Comment: Unfortunately, No. The given example passes all arguments to KCM as command line arguments, not in a yaml file. I was looking for option like kube-controller-manager --config=/etc/kcm-config.yaml

Comment: What do you mean? The accepted answer literally shows you how to pass arguments to the kcd with yaml file. There is no other way to do this.

Comment: I'm looking for kcm as we have for kubelet like this https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/#start-a-kubelet-process-configured-via-the-config-file . The one you showed was a yaml for a kube-controller-manager pod, not how to start the kcm process with a yaml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible ways of starting kube-controller-manager with customized settings, by providing YAML files.

##### Method #1

The `kube-controller-manager` runs as a pod in your control plane. It's config file is located in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests`, a `kube-controller-manager.yaml`. By adding `.spec.containers.command` like so:

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-controller-manager
    - --authentication-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf
...
```

you can change the defaults.

Then you would have to restart docker (or containerd)

```text
sudo systemctl restart docker (or containerd)
```

or, if you want to restart just `kube-controller-manager`

```text
docker restart kube-controller-mamnager
```

##### Method #2

You can change use `ClusterConfiguration` with `extraArgs` like so<sup>[[reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/control-plane-flags/#controllermanager-flags)]</sup>:

```yaml
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: v1.16.0
controllerManager:
  extraArgs:
    cluster-signing-key-file: /home/johndoe/keys/ca.key
    deployment-controller-sync-period: "50"
```

For this you would have to extract your current cluster configuration

```text
kubeadm config view > kubeadm-config.yaml
```

edit this file accordingly, and then upgrade the control plane

```text
kubeadm upgrade apply --config kubeadm-config.yaml
```

---

Now, to answer your question - `kube-controller-manager` does not support `--config` or any other flag that would allow you to pass a YAML file as it's argument (you can check all available flags [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-controller-manager/#options)).

The only possible solutions are the two above.

Comment: I have accepted Paweł Grondal's answer as that stated it right. What I'm trying to do is not available. As a workaround, to get what I am trying to, now I maintain 2 copies of the same certificate, so that I can use it during the rotation